# how to detect objects in images?

Tags: ios, opencv, image-recognition, object-detection, mser

I am trying to find options for detecting objects in image. Couple of options I found while researching are openCV and catchroom sdk.

Are there any other options that you have used or know of that works well? 
My use case is to detect all objects in an image and save them as separate images (with transparent background) ie. it should be able to detect boundaries as well.

It would be great if this can work on device ios/android sdk. If not, I can use some api/service.

Please advise.

Comment: This is quite broad for this site. It depends on what you want to do/need. Also, what have you tried so far, what technique are you going for (e.g Machine learning, feature descriptors, etc). You should choose one, try to do it and come back if something fails.

Comment: I know its broad, and may be stackoverflow is not the right place for this question. But, I have no idea about image processing/object detection. That's why I was hoping to may be at-least get some pointers.

Comment: A good start would be to read some of the tons of OpenCV books out there.

Comment: I'd suggest you searching for 'caffe' which are both are open source machine learning techniques to understand images.
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/image_recognition

Comment: If you're looking for a starting point to integrate TensorFlow, you can also have a look at this [guide and open-source example](https://v-play.net/cross-platform-development/machine-learning-add-image-classification-for-ios-and-android-with-qt-and-tensorflow).